# How to display the rows that matches specific numbers of time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanna show the rows that match specific numbers of time in dataframe.

All numbers are sorted, I know how to show if all numbers are matched, but **I don't know how to show if match 2, 3, 4, or non-mathes** dataframe.

```
check = [4,5,6,8,9]
my_list = list(range(0,10)) # generate non duplicate numbers from 0 to 9
n = []
trials = 5
for i in range(trials):
    t = random.sample(my_list, k=5)
    t.sort()
    n.append(t)
df = pd.DataFrame(n, columns=['Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5'])
df
```

| Num1 | Num2 | Num3 | Num4 | Num5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **4** | **5** | **6** | **8** | **9** |
| 0 | 3 | **5** | **8** | **9** |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | **5** | 7 |
| **5** | **6** | 7 | **8** | **9** |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | **4** | **6** |

If I want to **show all matches row**:

```
df_match5 = df[(df['Num1']==check[0]) & (df['Num2']==check[1]) & (df['Num3']==check[2]) & (df['Num4']==check[3]) & (df['Num5']==check[4])]
df_match5
```

| Num1 | Num2 | Num3 | Num4 | Num5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **4** | **5** | **6** | **8** | **9** |

If I want to **show match 1 time Only**:

```
df_match1 = do something
df_match1
```

| Num1 | Num2 | Num3 | Num4 | Num5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | **5** | 7 |

If I want to **show match 2 times Only**:

```
df_match2 = do something
df_match2
```

| Num1 | Num2 | Num3 | Num4 | Num5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | **4** | **6** |

And keep going for match 3,4,or non-mathes

Answer (score 0):

You can check if each dataframe value is in list then sum the result by columns

```py
times = 1
m = df.applymap(lambda x: x in check).sum(axis=1).eq(times)
out = df[m]
```

```
print(out)

   Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5
2     1     2     3     5     7
```